# Filter logging raw post data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a mobile app that is posting and receiving json to my rails app, the problem is that the raw json shows in my log. Is there a way to filter it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add to `filter_parameters`.  Here's the default one:

```
$ cat config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```

Comment: the problem is that the json in the raw post body isn't ending up as parameters, so they don't get filtered. I have added several in the config.